# Search Google Chrome web history for a PDF file

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, history

Is there any way to search in your Google Chrome history for a pdf file? I know you can accomplish this in the regular Google search box with `filetype:pdf`. But this does not work in the history search box.

This is the search box I am talking about:

[image]

In case it matters, I am using Google Chrome 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to search Chrome History by file type, but it might be possible to search by file type in Google Web History with `filetype:pdf` .When i try it out in my Google Web History i get just pdf files.

Comment: Seems like it [doesn't](https://myactivity.google.com/item?q=filetype:pdf) work anymore